# Code for either MS Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a program that uses either a SQL Server database or a MS Access database.

I'm trying to figure out a way to use either of the databases with the same code.  As an example you would do the folowing depending on what DB you're using:

SQL Server:

```
Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQLQuery, Connection)
    Using rs As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rs.Read
            ' Do something
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

MS Access:

```
Using cmd As OleDbCommand= New OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, Connection)
    Using rs As OleDbDataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rs.Read
            ' Do something
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

In my case , I could implement something like this:

```
Dim rs As New Object
Dim con As Object
Dim cmd As Object
If SQL-Server Then
    con = TryCast(conSQL-Server, SqlConnection)
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    rs = TryCast(rs, SqlDataReader)
Else
    con = TryCast(conMS-Access, OleDb.OleDbConnection)
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    rs = TryCast(rs, OleDb.OleDbDataReader)
End If   
Try
    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = SQLQuery
        rs = .ExecuteReader
    End With
    Do While rs.Read
        ' Do something
    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Handle Error        
Finally
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If Not rs.IsClosed Then rs.Close()
        rs.Dispose()
    End If
    cmd.Dispose()
End Try
```

but that's a lot of hassle.  It would be nice if you could create a custom type to do something like:

```
If SQL-Server Then
    DBCommand = SqlCommand
    DBReader = SqlDataReader
Else
    DBCommand = OleDbCommand
    DBReader = OleDbDataReader
End
Using cmd As DBCommand = New DBCommand(SQLQuery, connection)
    Using rs As DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rs.Read
            ' Do something
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if you treated them as interfaces (E.g., `IDbCommand`), they should share a common interface. Then it would be similar to the second scenario, where you have special setup code, but treat the rest of it as if it were the same object.  The data readers have `IDataReader`, etc.

Comment: Do you have an example of that?  I looked into it but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: there's a simplistic example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx  It just shows how the different types of commands can be treated as an `IDbCommand`.  This approach could be scaled out to meet your desired approach.

Comment: Keep in mind how completely different these platforms are. Also keep in mind that SQL Express LocalDB  is free https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx and MS Access is not. It may not be as good an idea as you think to try and get this to work transparently on different platforms.

Comment: Why don't you use factory?

Comment: Yes, I know there are considerable differences in the queries; however, I've already taken that into account.  The queries aren't that complicated for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer:

```
Dim con As IDbConnection
If SQL-Server Then
    con = conSQL-Server
Else
    con = conMS-Access
End If
Using cmd As IDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = SQLQuery
    Using rs As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rs.Read()
            ' Do something
        Loop       
    End Using
End Using
```

It's too bad CreateCommand doesn't take parameters.

Comment: You shouldn't need the casts.  If you did, you'd cast to `IDbConnection`, not the actual type..  Otherwise, it looks good.